# Trying to retrieve value from Firebase, but getting null?

Tags: java, firebase

As you can see from the code below, I output `retrievedValue` from inside `onDataChange()` which works as intended. But I can't output `retrievedValue` from another place because it returns `null`.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        retrievedValue = (Long) dataSnapshot.getValue();

        System.out.println(retrievedValue); //this line works
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});

System.out.println(retrievedValue); //this line returns null! How can I fix this?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this line returns null! How can I fix this?

I don't think you understand how asynchronous code works... First, nothing is returned null. Nothing has **been assigned** yet.

Your code is the exact same as this.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
System.out.println(retrievedValue); //this line returns null! 

ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        retrievedValue = (Long) dataSnapshot.getValue();

        System.out.println(retrievedValue); //this line works
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

There is nothing to fix because you are using Firebase wrong.

If you need `retrievedValue`, then you should put all related code into (or after, like via another method) `onDataChange`

For example

```
private Long retreivedValue; // starts as null

public static void updateSomething(Long data) {
    System.out.println(data); // this line works
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            retrievedValue = (Long) dataSnapshot.getValue();

            updateSomething(retrievedValue); 
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up. Then, how can I save `retrievedValue` so I can use it somewhere else?

Comment: You are saving it perfectly fine. You just have to **use** the value **after** `onDataChange` (and by after I mean "within")

Comment: Do you mean my only option is to use `retrievedValue` inside `onDataChange`?

Comment: Well, yes. Otherwise it is null. You can define method that use that value, though. Welcome to the world of callbacks